# How to write event handler for dynamic control?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Actually i am dynamicaly creating two textboxes and two buttons inside a table using for loop. Now i want to write event handlers for these 2 buttons so that upon clicking on the button the text inside the respective texbox should be displayed in a new label. Also tell me why upon clicking the button after postback all the dynamic controls disappear. Kindly explain with some good example.

Comment: is the question related to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .
    .
    Button Button1= new Button();
    Button1.ID = "button1";
    Button1.Text = "Button";
    Button1.Click+=new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
    this.form1.Controls.Add(Button1);
    .
    .
}
```

and handler method goes like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //
}
```

The reason why after postback all the buttons disappear is, these controls are not created again in `Page_Load` event.

These controls were not in page markup initially, and while postback, dynamically created markups will not be retained due to stateless transfer

Go through [ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more information